# Adding Variables in xCode 4's predicate editor

Tags: ios, xcode4, nspredicateeditor

I can't seem to find a way to add a fetch result with a variable in the new xCode4's editor...
I've looked every where... every right click, menu item, everything...

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean a template for a fetchRequest in the modelingtool? Try clicking in the topmenu bar >>Editor >> Add FetchRequest

Comment: yeah... I got that far... But I can't seem to be able to add a real template there... Only a static predicate... I can do a "age larger then 4" but not a "age larger then x" and be able to provide the x later in code.....